# Kafka Consumer error: System.InvalidOperationException: FATAL: Cannot marshal from a NULL ptr

Tags: c#, confluent-kafka-dotnet

```
Kafka Consumer error: System.InvalidOperationException: FATAL: Cannot marshal from a NULL ptr .
```

Any idea why this error is happening? This is with confluent kafka dot net nuget library.

Some cases consumer restart stops this error but again comes back after few days.

Comment: Please post the code that is actually getting the exception in your question. From the error message it looks like something is NULL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.